# Hibernate cannot create table when the entity annotation?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, tomcat7

My web project ,spring spring-mvc and hibernate,when the tomcat start there is no tables created in mysql db. why? and no error info

*the sessionFactory*

```
 <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
    <property name="hibernateProperties">  
        <props>  
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>  
        </props>  
    </property>   
   <property name="packagesToScan">  
        <list>  
            <value>com.woodcoder.bean</value>  
        </list>  
    </property>   
</bean>
```

*the properties*

```
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true  
hibernate.format_sql=false
```

and I tried  `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`, it's the same.
Why hibernate doesn't create a table?

The Entity

```
   @Entity
    @Table(name="user_bean")

public class UserBean extends BaseBean {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }


}
```

*the baseEntity*

```
 @MappedSuperclass  
public class BaseBean implements Serializable{  
    /** 
     * ID 
     */
    @Id  
    @Column(name="id",length = 32, nullable = true)  
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")  
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")  
    private String id;  

    @Column(updatable = false)
    private Date createDate;  

    private Date modifyDate;  


    public String getId() {  
        return id;  
    }  

    public void setId(String id) {  
        this.id = id;  
    }  

    public Date getCreateDate() {  
        return createDate;  
    }  

    public void setCreateDate(Date createDate) {  
        this.createDate = createDate;  
    }  

    public Date getModifyDate() {  
        return modifyDate;  
    }  

    public void setModifyDate(Date modifyDate) {  
        this.modifyDate = modifyDate;  
    }
```

Comment: Turn on debug logging (if you haven't).  Perhaps schema tooling is finding errors but you aren't seeing them due to a lower log level.  Secondly, make sure that your XML file is being properly substituted with values in your deployment war.  That can often be a reason why something doesn't happen.

Comment: as your suggest ,i lower the log level to DEBUG ,then i get more information,but no tables created. and i checked the deploy directory in the tomcat ,all properties and xml files have been deployed properly.

Answer (score 0):

yes,i got the problem.
in the hibernate config there are some space in the end of each line,although i cant see them.i delete these space,the table was created.

```
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=false
```